# Not able to import pandas in jupyter notebook for Google cloud instance

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I have done the setup of google cloud instance and also installed jupyter notebook. And I am able to start the jupyter notebook from my laptop. However when I run

```
import pandas as pd
```

[image]

It throws error. I tried to uninstall numpy and pandas and reinstall it from shell as well as from jupyter notebook. It does the new installation but again when I try to import pandas as pd, it still gives the same error.

What could be the error ? Is it something related to the path where it installs the library. How to debug this.

Comment: How did you install pandas?

Comment: !pip install pandas on jupyter and pip install pandas on shell